# Error 404 when trying to download Apache ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

When i type this in my bash:

```
wget http://www.apache.org/dist//activemq/apache-activemq/5.5.0/apache-activemq-5.5.0-bin.tar.gz
```

I get the following:

```
--2020-02-17 11:21:20--  http://www.apache.org/dist//activemq/apache-activemq/5.5.0/apache-activemq-5.5.0-bin.tar.gz
Resolving www.apache.org (www.apache.org)... 40.79.78.1, 95.216.24.32, 2a01:4f9:2a:185f::2
Connecting to www.apache.org (www.apache.org)|40.79.78.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://downloads.apache.org/activemq/apache-activemq/5.5.0/apache-activemq-5.5.0-bin.tar.gz [following]
--2020-02-17 11:21:21--  https://downloads.apache.org/activemq/apache-activemq/5.5.0/apache-activemq-5.5.0-bin.tar.gz
Resolving downloads.apache.org (downloads.apache.org)... 88.99.95.219, 2a01:4f8:10a:201a::2
Connecting to downloads.apache.org (downloads.apache.org)|88.99.95.219|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-02-17 11:21:21 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Why am I getting an error 404?

Comment: Because it's not there... https://downloads.apache.org/activemq/
For this older release use:
http://archive.apache.org/dist/activemq/apache-activemq/5.5.0/apache-activemq-5.5.0-bin.tar.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only **recent** Apache ActiveMQ releases are available on https://downloads.apache.org/activemq/. Older releases (e.g. 5.5.0) are available in the archive area at http://archive.apache.org/dist/activemq/. This is in accordance with [Apache release policy](http://www.apache.org/legal/release-policy.html#when-to-archive).

The specific release you're looking for is in http://archive.apache.org/dist/activemq/apache-activemq/5.5.0/. This is linked from the [Apache ActiveMQ website](https://activemq.apache.org/activemq-550-release).